# unix snmp - difference between system and kernel cpu time

Tags: unix, snmp

Performing an snmpwalk on OID .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11 produces the following `CpuRaw` values:

```
UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawUser.0 = Counter32: 3191634181
UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawNice.0 = Counter32: 2586628
UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawSystem.0 = Counter32: 480833488
UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawIdle.0 = Counter32: 3578238833
UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawWait.0 = Counter32: 461331879
UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawKernel.0 = Counter32: 422462005
UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawInterrupt.0 = Counter32: 7890770
UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawSoftIRQ.0 = Counter32: 50480713
```

I note that all values, with the exception of `idle` + `kernel`, have matching values (close enough) in `/proc/stat`:

```
cpu  3191634876 2586629 422462086 7873206561 461331924 7890771 50480723 0
cpu0 1551975573 184783 190766514 1008267162 200070032 7243827 44073977 0
cpu1 610948559 324197 73381486 2228315579 87505437 51905 2054732 0
cpu2 494534866 1024716 75891701 2342123809 86260984 289810 2089023 0
cpu3 534175876 1052931 82422383 2294500009 87495469 305228 2262989 0
 intr 8208380331 4267093007 3 0 4 4 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3538 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 328178999 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 997463093 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2374098089 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 241543587 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
ctxt 163836165157
btime 1351100022
processes 224876777
procs_running 5
procs_blocked 0
```

I'd like to know what the difference is between `ssCpuRawSystem`and `ssCpuRawKernel` and how this relates to the contents of `/proc/stat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssCpuRawSystem

The number of 'ticks' (typically 1/100s) spent
processing system-level code.

On a multi-processor system, the 'ssCpuRaw*'
counters are cumulative over all CPUs, so their
sum will typically be N*100 (for N processors).

This object may sometimes be implemented as the
combination of the 'ssCpuRawWait(54)' and
'ssCpuRawKernel(55)' counters, so care must be
taken when summing the overall raw counters.

ssCpuRawKernel

The number of 'ticks' (typically 1/100s) spent
processing kernel-level code.

This object will not be implemented on hosts where
the underlying operating system does not measure
this particular CPU metric.  This time may also be
included within the 'ssCpuRawSystem(52)' counter.

On a multi-processor system, the 'ssCpuRaw*'
counters are cumulative over all CPUs, so their
sum will typically be N*100 (for N processors).